# How do I configure pip.conf in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to deploy a Python application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, however this module requires dependencies from our private PyPi index. How can I configure pip (like what you do with ~/.pip/pip.conf) so that AWS can connect to our private index while deploying the application?

My last resort is to modify the dependency in `requirements.txt` to `-i URL dependency` before deployment, but there must be a clean way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .ebextensions/files.config add something like this:

```
files:
    "/opt/python/run/venv/pip.conf":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        user: root
        content: |
            [global]
            find-links = <URL>
            trusted-host = <HOST>
            index-url = <URL>
```

Or whatever other configurations you'd like to set in your pip.conf. This will place the pip.conf file in the virtual environment of your application, which will be activated before `pip -r requirements.txt` is executed. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I ended up doing a similar thing, putting a script in the 'files:' section and running it later in 'commnads:'.

Comment: @n0rm1e Could you elaborate? I'm facing the same issue, have tried the answer above, also tried adding to different dirs: /root/.pip /home/ec2-user... nothing seems to work